# How to save & retrieve image in Database from PictureBox control in windows Forms (VB.NET)

Tags: sql, windows, vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I am having trouble in browse & then save an image to SQL Server.ALso I want to retrieve that image.

This is the code to browse image & show it in PictureBox1 Control

```
Public Sub SelectImage()

    With OpenFileDialog1
        '.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        .Filter = "All Files|*.*|Bitmaps|*.bmp|GIFs|*.gif|JPEGs|*.jpg"
        .FilterIndex = 4
    End With

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    End If
```

I have created a image feild in a table & this is my stored procedure

```
  Public Sub Insert_Update_Personal()
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("sp_Insert_Update_Personal", con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", UploadImage)      
    LastPID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()
```

But don't know how to pass it to image parameter & Please suggest .Also is there any way that I can save image on Local drive & just save the url /location/name in database?

Which method would be better

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another approach, try this to save your image file localy and load them without storeing them in database. 
Note: picPath is the path of the image file, you can use openfiledialog or other method to set it in lblPhoto.text

```
Private Sub SavePhoto()
Try
Dim picPath As String = ""
Dim picName As String = ""
picPath = lblPhoto.Text
If lblPhoto.Text = "" Then
picName = (txtimage.Text + ".tus")
End If
If picPath <> "" And (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Photo\\" + picName) = True) Then
File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Photo\\" + picName)
Else
picName = (txtimage.Text + ".tus")
File.Copy(picPath, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Photo\\" + picName, True)
End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try

End Sub
```

Now to load the saved photo do the following

```
If (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Photo\" + txtimage.Text + ".tus") = True) Then
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Photo\" + txtPolicy_No.Text + ".tus", True)
End If
```